# How to access field from related record via What or Who field?

Tags: apex, lookup

Accessing fields from related records via custom lookup fields works like this: `object.lookup_field__r.Name`
This piece of code would return the `Name` of the related record via custom lookup field `lookup_field__c`.

I can see that `What` and `Who` on `Task` object are somehow different.

Is it possible to access a field via `What` or `Who` lookups in the same or similar manner like I mentioned above?

I used to access fields by querying related records by `WhatId` and `WhoId` but it gets quite complicated, I am searching for clean and short approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to identify related object by its id in code or in formula field

example : - add a formula field and have this formula in it to get 'What' related object name

```
CASE(LEFT( WhatId , 3), '001', 'Account', '003','Contact','006','Opportunity','00Q','Lead','Other')
```

once you identify object, write a dynamic SOQL and use it.

let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you Megha, I'm already doing it using this approach. I thought there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

**PS** Apologies, this is still documented as "**Developer Preview**", so this answer is more of an FYI. Just appears to be turned on in my developer edition org.

SOQL will sometime have "polymorphic" syntax to help query where a reference can be to various SObject types - see e.g. [TYPEOF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) .

So if you have a Tasks where the WhoId references both Contact and Lead, you can run a query of this form to get the name for both types:

```
Task[] tasks = [select typeof Who when Contact then Name when Lead then Name end from Task];
for (Task t : tasks) {
    System.debug('>>> ' + t.Who.Name);
}
```